# Does the Finnish translative case exist in other languages?

Tags: cases, finnish

The Finnish translative case expresses the concept of becoming or turning into something else. Does this case exist in other languages, or is it unique to Finnish? How is this concept most commonly expressed in other inflected languages?

Comment: Note that translative is also used for path; some researchers also use the term "mutative" for "translative" as used in Finno-Ugric studies etc. For  more details see http://www.oxfordhandbooks.com/view/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780199206476.001.0001/oxfordhb-9780199206476

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The case is not unique to Finnish alone; its relatives, such as Estonian and Hungarian, have it too.

That said, it appears to be quite unique to the Finno-Ugric family, to which all of the above languages belong.

Answer (score -1):

It is also present in Armenian language like:

- **հայ** - *hay* - Armenian (for person/people/nation) --- **հայերեն** - *hayeren* - Armenian (for language)
- **հայերեն** - *hayeren* - Armenian (for languagge) --- **հայերենում** - *hayerenum* - In Armenian (for language)
- **անգլիա** - *anglia* - England --- **անգլերեն** - *angleren* - English

Am I understood right?

Comment: no, this not the case.

Comment: I know that fist and third one does not fit in but what about second one? This is not the case as well?

Comment: Is հայերենում a noun or is it an adverb? If it's adverb then -ւմ is not a case ending